# Angularjs printing the list elements multiple time

Tags: angularjs, list

I am very new to aj. Below is my angular js code.I am creating the list of dictionaries in controller.I am calling controller function add() from ui as shown below:

```
   <html>
    <head>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
          <div ng-app="appTable">
             <div ng-controller="Allocation">
             {{ add()}}
             {{dataList}}
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("appTable", []);

        app.controller("Allocation", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.dataList = [];
            $scope.add = function() {
                var data = {};
                data = {
                    "date": '11'
                };
                $scope.dataList.push(data);
            };
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Output is:

```
[{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"},{"date":"11"}]
```

But as per my understanding output should be,

```
[{"date":"11"}]
```

Please help.

Comment: Call it on button click and i think it should work as per your expected answer.You can pass this method using **ng-click** attribute of angular js .

Comment: Is there not any other way without using button?Why button(ng-click) required?Any specific reason?

Comment: You can use some conditions in your js which will check and display your data accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-init to call function only once when page loads. See this:

```js
        var app = angular.module("appTable", []);

        app.controller("Allocation", function($scope) {
            $scope.dataList = [];
            $scope.add = function() {
                var data = {};
                data = {
                    "date": '11'
                };
                $scope.dataList.push(data);
            };
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
       <body>
          <div ng-app="appTable">
             <div ng-controller="Allocation">
             <span ng-init="add()"></span>
             {{dataList}}
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
  
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes answer is as per my exception.But why some event is required?What is happening in background?Can u throw some light on it?

Comment: Put debugger on Add function at controller side. You will see it calls function for multiple times. And also ng-init is not a event.  see this for detail : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Also calling add on this way it creates loop of $digest cycle so that gives this error and display data multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

When you call any event on page load directly then it goes to infinite $digest() loop.

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. AngularJS detects this situation and **prevents an infinite loop** from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any event. You can use self invoking function and remove **{{add()}}** from your HTML

```
  $scope.add = function() {
         var data = {};
         data = {
                 "date": '11'
         };
         $scope.dataList.push(data);
   }();
```

Comment: So this is like constructor?Isn't it?It will be only called at starting...

Comment: A self-invoking function is function which invokes itself. It enables you to execute code once right after it has been defined

Comment: @spaceearth Mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful.